# How to make ASP.NET Core (v3.1) Web API accepts child class parameter from body

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I am now making an API to accept third party token info and store it into DB.
The class definition like:

```
public class ThirdPartyBaseToken
{
    [JsonProperty("accessToken")]
    public virtual string AccessToken { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("brand")]
    public virtual string Brand { get; set; }
}
```

And the API in controller like:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> SaveTokenAsync([FromBody]ThirdPartyBaseToken tokenBody)
{
    var request = new SavingRequest
    {
        ThirdPartyToken = tokenBody.AccessToken,
        ……
        ……
    };
    
    await backendService.SaveAsync(request);

    return this.StatusCode(201);
}
```

However I met some exceptions and after I did the investigation, I found the property names from some third parties were "accessToken", but others were "openToken".
In this case, I created a child class inherited from base class and override the JsonProperty like:

```
public class ThirdPartyChildToken: ThirdPartyBaseToken
{
    [JsonProperty("openToken")]
    public override string AccessToken { get; set; }
}
```

I hope once the "openToken" property comes, the API can accept it and get the token info from AccessToken correctly.
Unfortunately, I debugged locally and I found the AccessToken was still null, which means the JsonProperty("openToken") did not work.

Could someone give me some instructions to resolve the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I feel like from a design standpoint, it would be best to keep the convention that the property names match the JSON property names. So, you could add both properties, and then check which one is not null.

```
public string GetToken()
    => this.AccessToken ?? this.OpenToken ?? throw new Exception("Token is null.");
```

This convention also has the advantage, that you don't have to specify every `[JsonProperty]` attribute explicitly.

Comment: Thank you, there is no doubt your solution can resolve my problem, however I am curious whether I can find an elegant solution. If I cannot find some better solutions, I will apply your suggestion.

Comment: @OceanSun I know what you mean, but my point was actually, that I consider this the most elegant and proper design. If you find any other solutions, I would still be curious to hear though.

Comment: Thank you, I considered another solution (I am not sure whether it can achieve). The solution is, I want to create a new attribute named JsonProperties inherit from JsonProperty, and this child class can accept multi JSON key names like: [JsonProperties(["accessToken", "openToken"])] and re-write the JsonHandler to accept the requests from invoker. But now I will use your solution since I do not want to spend more time on this issue.

Comment: @OceanSun Keep me posted. It's an interesting problem. Still not sure which approach I'd prefer. So far, I still find this solution the most straightforward. Yours sounds also good, I do see some issues though, and it's probably a lot of work, as I imagine you'd have to write a custom JsonSerializer.